# Does Pokemon Go have a minimum resolution requirement?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm looking to buy a budget phone which has a 480x854 screen resolution. While Googling for Pokemon Go's requirements, all I see is that a minimum resolution of 720p is *recommended*, but I couldn't find any minimum required.

Will Pokemon Go work in such a small screen? The phone is an Asus ZB452KG with Android 4.4 and a quad core CPU, so I'm only worried about the screen.

Comment: From what I can see, that phone doesn't have a gyroscope. If I'm not mistaken, that means it won't support Pokémon Go, regardless of screen resolution.

Comment: The game should still work with augmented reality mode switched off in settings, even without a gyroscope.

Answer (score 1):

There is no resolution requirement for Pokémon GO, it should work fine on your phone.

As Nolonar pointed out, the phone doesn't have a gyroscope in it, however the app should still run fine with the augmented reality mode switched of in settings.

Answer (score 0):

My screen is 480p and works fine.
Just some lag but that's because my phone is just cheap in general.

Should still work.